# Why is my art displayed at 2x on screen?

Tags: image, sprite-kit, scale, retina-display, skspritenode

I am creating a Universal App.

I have created my art in illustrator to fit properly on an iPhone screen, specifically at 640x1136 px. I exported PNGs and named myArt@2x.png and also a 50% version named myArt.png. The art is in an atlas folder.

I am creating sprite nodes a like this:

```
NSString * backgroundName=@"starField";
SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:backgroundName];
background.position = CGPointMake(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2);
background.zPosition = LayerBackground;
[_worldNode addChild:background];
```

The problem is that when I run this in the simulator (iPhone 4 w/retina), the images are scaled up. I have to ousel xScale and yScale to bring it back to actual size.

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
rich!

Comment: What is the scene's scaleMode set to?

Comment: I tried all the modes and none of them make a difference...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the size property of the SKNode I think. For example:

```
background.size = CGSizeMake(screenWidth, screenHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I solved it -

I don't start creating my content until **viewWillLayoutSubviews** had been called. The default *SpritKit* Template uses **viewDidLoad**, but I changed that to **viewWillLayoutSubviews** and everything looks fine now.

I think I was trying to create stuff before the view "sorted" itself out...

Not sure what the difference is but it worked.

-r